# All-day-event notification: how to get notified during event, on the same day?

Tags: google-calendar

On the Google Calendar page I can access via a web browser, I can click on:

`Settings cogwheel` | `Calendars` | to the right of any calendar entry click `Edit notifications`.

The help icon next to `All-day event notifications:` says:

> Event notifications tell you about an all-day event at a specified
>   time some number of days before it begins. For example, if you’d like
>   to be alerted about an all-day event at 9 am the day before it occurs,
>   you’d set a notification.

However, IMHO there are several use cases where one would need to be notified during the same day about an all-day event. The classical scenario is birthdays. I don't want to know about them the day before, but during the same day, perhaps in the morning around 8:30, or perhaps in the afternoon after work hours around 7:00 PM, these are the times when I would like the notification to be sent out for such all-day events, not the day before.

- Is there a way to configure such behavior in Google calendar, and if not then why is it missing / why is it not possible to program such behavior into Google calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, perhaps the help message had some issues, but now I see that when I go to a specific calendar's `Settings | Edit notifications` tab I have the opportunity to set the following under "All-day event notifications:" which would pertain to the selected calendar whose settings I would be configuring:

- Notification method: pop-up, e-mail, or SMS
- specify 0 days before event to have the event reminder on the very same day
- specify the time (e.g. 6:30) you want to be notified about the event

You can even set more than one notification of the same type for either all-day events or regular events, and can set as many plans to receive notifications as you want.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work anymore :( When I set "0 days before" calendar doesn't notify via popup or any chrome notification at all. Same situation with Android Google Calendar App. Popup works only when I set ">0 (1,2...) day(s) before", but email works even with "0 days before".

Comment: @b0rman As of 2022-10-28 it seems to work again (tested on desktop webapp and Google Calendar app for Android).

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't work. I tried and thought it will trigger a notification at 12 am but it didn't.

Best solution is to set as 'event' at 12am the same day.
As Google calendar doesn't snooze (baffles me still why such a simple tool can't be configured,  it's 2016 for crying out loud ),  I have downloaded Calendar Snooze at my android to work with GCal.

Comment: Please do not include additional questions in the answer space.

Answer (score 0):

This was not working for me when I tried to get notifications on my phone for a Facebook birthdays via an ical feed.

After a lot of troubleshooting, this finally seemed to work:

1. Create ical Calendar using HTTPS link instead of webcal link. Example: https://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?uid=XXXXXXXXX&key=YYYYYYYYYY
2. Import your Calendar via URL
3. Enable your Calendar here: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect
4. Go to your phone, head over to Calendar app. Turn syncing off for that Calendar, remove any All-day event notification settings.
5. Now add the desired All-day notification setting and turn syncing back on. You should now receive notifications properly going forward.